# Swift label not displaying what the selected cell says

Tags: uitableview, swift, uilabel

I have a tableview that is populated with information from a JSON array. I want to make each selected cell segue into a viewController, and in that viewController I have a label the should display what the selected cell says. For example if my cell says California, when I click on the cell it'll open up my viewController and the label would say California.

Seems simple enough, and I've done this before successfully, however this time I'm using JSON to populate my tableView and I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong. With the code posted below, when I click on a cell the titleLabel doesn't even show up.
(My tableView file and DetailsViewController file are posted below, any other swift file I used can be found in my previous question [populating Tableview with a function that uses SwiftyJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663965/populating-tableview-with-a-function-that-uses-swiftyjson))

```
import UIKit

class EarthTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var info = [AppModel]()



    func getEarthquakeInfo(completion: (results : NSArray?) ->Void ){

        DataManager.getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess {
            (data) -> Void in

                let json = JSON(data: data)


                if let JsonArray =  json.array {

                    for appDict in JsonArray {
                        var ids: String? = appDict["id"].stringValue
                        var title: String? = appDict["title"].stringValue
                        var time: String? = appDict["time"].stringValue
                        var information = AppModel(idEarth: ids, title: title, time: time)

                        self.info.append(information)
                        completion(results: self.info)
                    }


            }

        }



    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getEarthquakeInfo { (info) in

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let infoArray = self.info


        cell.textLabel!.text = self.info[indexPath.row].title



        return cell



    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if segue.identifier == "SEGUE" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as DetailsViewController
            let cell = (sender as UITableViewCell)

             let title = cell.textLabel!.text

            vc.titleData = title


        }





    }







    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return info.count
    }

}
```

My DetailsViewController file:

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var idLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    var titleData: String!
    var idData: String!
    var timeData: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var earthInfo = EarthTableViewController()
        var getEarthInfo: () = earthInfo.getEarthquakeInfo { (info) in
            println("\(info)")



        }


        titleLabel.text = titleData
        idLabel.text = idData
       timeLabel.text = timeData
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



}
```

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint into prepareForSegue(). Is there a segue with id SEGUE? What is the value of title variable inside that function?

Comment: if you want to send a string using segue,use setter method. It is very easy

Comment: @Alexey I forgot to put SEGUE as my segue Identifier -_- Huge mistake by me. It's working now.